# Swap data between two checked elements

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is a somewhat simplified version of the code I am currently using:

https://jsfiddle.net/2zauty83/8/

Javascript

```
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup) {
  var checkgroup = checkgroup
  for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++) {
    checkgroup[i].onclick = function() {
      var checkedcount = 0
      for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++)
        checkedcount += (checkgroup[i].checked) ? 1 : 0
      if (checkedcount > 2) {
        this.checked = false
      }
    }
  }
}

var sort_form = document.forms.sortus;
var sort_checkboxes = sort_form.elements['squarepick[]'];
checkboxlimit(sort_checkboxes);
```

CSS

```
input.square {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

.sorttile {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  margin: 1px;
}

.sorttile:hover {
  border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
}
```

HTML

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' id='sortus'>
  <input id='1-1' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='1-1' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='1-1' style='background-color:#FF0000;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='1-1' value='#FF0000' />
  </label>
  <input id='1-2' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='1-2' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='1-2' style='background-color:#FFFF00;'>
<input type='hidden' name='1-2' value='#FFFF00' />
  </label>
  <input id='1-3' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='1-3' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='1-3' style='background-color:#00FF00;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='1-3' value='#00FF00' />
  </label>
  <br/>
  <input id='2-1' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='2-1' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='2-1' style='background-color:#00FFFF;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='2-1' value='#00FFFF' />
  </label>
  <input id='2-2' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='2-2' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='2-2' style='background-color:#0000FF;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='2-2' value='#0000FF' />
  </label>
  <input id='2-3' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='2-3' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='2-3' style='background-color:#FF00FF;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='2-3' value='#FF00FF' />
  </label>
  <br/>
  <input id='3-1' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='3-1' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='3-1' style='background-color:#000000;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='3-1' value='#000000' />
  </label>
  <input id='3-2' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='3-2' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='3-2' style='background-color:#999999;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='3-2' value='#999999' />
  </label>
  <input id='3-3' class='square' type='checkbox' name='squarepick[]' value='3-3' />
  <label class='sorttile' for='3-3' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='3-3' value='#FFFFFF' />
  </label>
</form>
```

Basically each colored square represents a checkbox, allowing you to select any two boxes. Additionally, each box has a hidden input field associated with it.

For simplified demonstration purposes, the demo uses "background-color", but my actual code uses "background-image".

What I would like to do is make it so that when two squares are picked, upon selecting the second box, the two boxes trade each other's "background-image" values, effectively making it appear like the two squares traded places.

In addition, however, I also need to swap the values of the hidden-type input fields.

Finally, the two checkboxes should be deselected, although that part is easy. What I'm having trouble with is the first two parts. I thought I had some idea of how to make it work, but my experiments haven't been working out (My knowledge of javascript is still fairly crude).

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is set up an event listener so you know when a box has been checked. The second thing you need to do is to keep track of what got checked. Finally, you want to perform a series of operations based on what was checked.

```
var formEl = document.getElementById("sortus");

// Track our checked boxes
var checked = [];

var swap = function () {
  var boxA = checked[0];
  var boxB = checked[1];
  // Get hidden fields using checkbox ID
  var hiddenA = document.getElementsByName(boxA.id)[0];
  var hiddenB = document.getElementsByName(boxB.id)[0];
  var boxAbackgroundImage = boxA.style.backgroundImage;
  var hiddenAvalue = hiddenA.value;
  // Switch images!
  boxA.style.backgroundImage = boxB.style.backgroundImage;
  boxB.style.backgroundImage = boxAbackgroundImage;
  // Swap hidden input values
  hiddenA.value = hiddenB.value;
  hiddenB.value = hiddenAvalue;
};

var reset = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
      checked[i].checked = false;
  }
  checked = [];
};

var isDuplicate = function (el) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
        if (checked[i] === el) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

formEl.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var el = e.target;
    // Was it a checkbox clicked?
    if (el.className == "square") {
        // Is it already checked?
        if (!isDuplicate(el)) {
            checked.push(el);
            if (checked.length === 2) {
                swap();
                reset();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I didn't test this code but I hope it gives you a clear sense of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basic function for your above requirement can be found in the below link,

[Fiddler Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2zauty83/13/)

```
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup) 
{
    var checkgroup = checkgroup
    for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++) {
        checkgroup[i].onclick = function() 
        {
        var checkedcount = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++)
            checkedcount += (checkgroup[i].checked) ? 1 : 0
        if (checkedcount > 2) {
            this.checked = false
        }
        swapImage();
    }
    }
}

function swapImage()
{
    var prevStyle="";
    var prevId="";
    for (var i = 0; i < sort_checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if(sort_checkboxes[i].checked)
        {
            if(prevId!="")
            {
document.getElementById(prevId).nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = sort_checkboxes[i].nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor;
document.getElementById(prevId).nextElementSibling.children[0].value = sort_checkboxes[i].nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor;
sort_checkboxes[i].nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = prevStyle;
sort_checkboxes[i].nextElementSibling.children[0].value = prevStyle;

prevStyle = "";
prevId = "";
            }
            else
            {
                prevId=sort_checkboxes[i].id;
                prevStyle = sort_checkboxes[i].nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Played around with this one, it works for the swapping background images issue. I'm still stuck on how to handle the corresponding hidden inputs though.

Comment: i had updated the post.. can you please check that too.. check the swapimage function